# Force geopy to return multipolygon

Tags: python, django, geodjango, shapely, geopy

Geopy's Geocoder wont return with a consistent object type. Depending on the search term, it may return a Polygon or a MultiPolygon.

GeoDjango (Postgis) wont let me enter a Polygon in a Multipolygon field.

**Can I ask geopy to always return a MultiPolygon?**

Comment: 1. Did you mean Nominatim rather than geopy? https://geopy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#geopy-is-not-a-service ; 2. I'm afraid it is not possible to retrieve MultiPolygon for objects which are not MultiPolygons from Nominatim. For example, roads are marked up as lines instead of polygons: https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/details.php?osmtype=W&osmid=5749671&class=highway

Comment: @KostyaEsmukov, you are rigth. Its Nominatim. The problem is integrating with GeoDjango, which creates tables in PostGis that accepts a single type: Polygon XOR Multipolygon.

Comment: If you need to store anything Nominatim might return, then you might want to consider using [GeometryField](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/281695) or [GeometryCollectionField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/model-api/#geometrycollectionfield) instead of MultiPolygonField.